# c++ simulate faux mouse press to trigger refresh glfw

Tags: c++, input, glfw

I'm looking for a way to simulate the right key mouse press and release after a function in my program is called. Currently, the only way the screen will refresh after a change in the camera view is when I click the right click button on my mouse.

I'm unable to find the place in the code that sets this trigger, hence why I would like to find a way to trigger the mouse click so that the screen refresh can happen without needing for the user to click the mouse.

The input system I am using is GLFW.

A sample of how I currently detect keypresses is as follows:

```
int currbutton = glfwGetMouseButton(handle, GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT);
    glfwGetCursorPos(handle, &mousex, &mousey);
    if (state == GLFW_PRESS && rbuttonstate == GLFW_RELEASE)
    {
      glfwGetCursorPos(handle, &mousex, &mousey);
      oldMousePos = glm::vec2((float)mousex, (float)mousey);
    }
 rbuttonstate = state;
```

Any help is appreciated for this.

Comment: Simulating input to get a certain side-effect is a fragile hack. You would be better off directly triggering a refresh.

Comment: Let's see... real issue is how to trigger a screen refresh. It is believed that this will be resolved by simulating a mouse click. Question was about the secondary issue. Secondary issue is a poor way to resolve the real issue. Yep, that's a pretty good fit to [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). On the plus side, you did mention the real issue, which is more than many do.

Comment: @JaMiT yes, but even when I call for a screenrefresh directly after my camera view changes, for only this case, it doesn't refresh, only when the right click is pressed. But in other instances the refresh button works fine. So I am literally very confused why the refresh() function i have refuses to work for this situation - hence why i was considering this hack of triggering the right click as a work-around. :(